# Dell Inspirion fan speed control

Tags: windows-8, fan, dell-inspiron

My Dell Inspirion 15 notebook routinely slows down after some period of gaming and I suspect it is due to heating up. None of regular fan speed control software - e.g. SpeedFan, MSI Afterburner - shows either CPU or GPU fans. Some older articles on the net suggest I8kfanGUI utility, but it wasn't updated for some years and either don't see fans too or is not compatible with Windows 8 that my notebook uses.

Is there any other options to control fan speed on this notebook?

Comment: which dell laptop do you have in detail? My 7520 (15RSE) sees the fans in SPeedfan.

Comment: I now vote to close it as "too broad". Without the exact Model we can't help you.